# Parsing JSON string in jquery

Tags: jquery, sql-server, json

I have an SQL server database in which I'm trying to store JSON strings as NVARCHAR(MAX). I construct an object like this:

```
var dataObject = new Object();
dataObject.text = [];
dataObject.option = [];
dataObject.answers = [];
```

I fill these arrays with strings and objects and I use JSON.stringify(dataObject) to get a Json string like this:

```
{"text":["Testno besedilo"],"option":["0"],"answers":[[{"text":"prvi","correct":1},{"text":"drugi","correct":0}]]}
```

When I retrieve the string from the database it looks like this:

```
"{&quot;text&quot;:[&quot;Testno besedilo&quot;],&quot;option&quot;:[&quot;0&quot;],&quot;answers&quot;:[[{&quot;text&quot;:&quot;prvi&quot;,&quot;correct&quot;:1},{&quot;text&quot;:&quot;drugi&quot;,&quot;correct&quot;:0}]]}"
```

I can't parse it with parseJSON(), I must be doing something wrong along the way, I'm not sure what. The first string looks like a correct JSON. Any help would be much appreciated?

Edit:

My MVC Model:

```
public class CustomModels : DbContext
{

    public CustomModels()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Quizzes> Quizzes { get; set; }

}

[Table("Quizzes")]
public class Quizzes
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Services")]
    public int ServiceID { get; set; }

    public virtual Services Services { get; set; }

    public string QuizName { get; set; }

    public string QuizData { get; set; }
}
```

The Action with which I pass my ID between views:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int? QuizId)
    {
        if (QuizId.HasValue)
        {

            CustomModels db = new CustomModels();
            var quiz = db.Quizzes.Find(QuizId);

            ViewData["QuizId"] = quiz;
        }

        return View("../EditKviz/Index");
    }
```

Comment: Try with JSON.parse(dataObject) or $.parseJSON(dataObject)

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe more about how you return you data from your database to your javascript. It seems like you forget to urlDecode the tekst before you give it to you Javascript like:

```
Server.UrlDecode("{&quot;text&quot;:[&quot;Testno besedilo&quot;],&quot;option&quot;:[&quot;0&quot;],&quot;answers&quot;:[[{&quot;text&quot;:&quot;prvi&quot;,&quot;correct&quot;:1},{&quot;text&quot;:&quot;drugi&quot;,&quot;correct&quot;:0}]]}");
```

Comment: I have a MVC.NET application, so I have a Model with a DbSet of objects that have the same data as the database table.

I'm passing a ID between views and I use the ID to find the object from the DbSet.